# Node.js, Sequelize, cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on an API and have a special problem. When a make a GET request, i received my JSON Data but the server crash with an error :

```
for (const key of Object.keys(this.constructor._attributeManipulation)) {
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/quentin/O'Clock/motogpapi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:83:34)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

I can't undersant origin of this crash. you can find below the code. Is it possible this problem due to as wrong data into db ?

Model team.js:

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../database/client");

class Teams extends Model {}

Teams.init({
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  constructorId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  isOfficial: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false
  },
  championshipId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
}, {
  sequelize,
  tableName: "team"
});


module.exports = Teams;
```

Model Constructor.js

```js
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../database/client");

class Constructors extends Model {}

Constructors.init({
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  model: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  engine: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
}, {
  sequelize,
  tableName: "constructor"
});


module.exports = Constructors;
```

Model Index.js i used for associations

```js
const Teams = require("./teams");
const Championships = require("./championships");
const Constructors = require("./constructors");

Constructors.hasMany(Teams, {
  foreignKey: "constructorId",
  as: "teamsList"
});
Teams.belongsTo(Constructors, {
  foreignKey: "constructorId",
  as: "constructor"
});

Championships.hasMany(Teams, {
  foreignKey: "championshipId",
  as: "teamsList"
});
Teams.belongsTo(Championships, {
  foreignKey: "championshipId",
  as: "championship"
});

module.exports = {
  Teams,
  Championships,
  Constructors
};
```

The Controller :

```js
const { Teams } = require("../models");

const teamsController = {
  async getAllTeams(_, response) {
    try {
      const teamsList = await Teams.findAll({
        include: ["constructor", "championship"]
      });
      response.json(teamsList);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = teamsController;
```

And database/client.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();

const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.PG_URL, {
  define: {
    underscored: true
  }
});

(async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
})();

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Comment: Show `database/client`

Comment: I just edited my post with database/client

Comment: Did you try to indicate `include` in the full its notation as objects with `model` and `as` options?

Comment: Finally found solution.

I used model and alias named 'constructor' and this name is reserved by Sequelize.